# how to saved different sheet from excel file to mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a code that importing and displaying a excel file to datagridview and I'm wondering if you help me to how can I save those sheet from my excel file to my database in mysql?? My sheet name are 1st grading, 2nd grading and attendance, I'm using `c#`. Anyway here's my code:

```
private void btnSaved_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int qtr = 0;
            string att_qtr = "ATTENDANCE";

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server = DESKTOP-9H7QBOH; Database = sti_spms; UID = root; Password = 1234;");
                try
                {
                    string query = "INSERT INTO tbl_secondsem_grades(STUDENT_NO, NAME, SUBJECT, SECTION, GRADE, INITIAL_GRADE, QTR)" + "Values(@STUDENT_NO, @NAME, @SUBJECT, @SECTION, @GRADE, @INITIAL_GRADE, @QTR)";
                    query += "INSERT INTO tbl_attendance(STUDENT_ID, NAME, SUBJECT, SECTION, TOTAL_ABSENCES)" + "Values(@STUDENT_ID, @NAME, @SUBJECT, @SECTION, @TOTAL_ABSENCES)";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    con.Open();
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1; i++)
                    {

                        if(quarter.Equals("1st QTR"))
                        {
                            qtr = 1;
                        }
                        else if(quarter.Equals("2nd QTR"))
                        {
                            qtr = 2;
                        }
                        else if(quarter.Equals("3rd QTR"))
                        {
                            qtr = 3;
                        }
                        else if(quarter.Equals("4th QTR"))
                        {
                            qtr = 4;
                        }
                        else if (quarter.Equals("ATTENDANCE"))
                        {
                            att_qtr = "ATTENDANCE";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Error!");
                        }

                        //int num = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["STUDENT NO"].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUDENT_NO", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["STUDENT NO"].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["NAME"].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUBJECT", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["SUBJECT"].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SECTION", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["SECTION"].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INITIAL_GRADE", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["INITIAL GRADE"].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GRADE", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["QG"].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTR", qtr);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUDENT_NO", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["STUDENT NO"].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["NAME"].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUBJECT", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["SUBJECT"].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SECTION", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["SECTION"].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Absences", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Total_Absences"].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data  Sucessfully Saved!");
                }

        }
```

Comment: And what issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: What is going wrong with your code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya my error is STUDENT_NO is already define.

Comment: @PaulF it said that STUDENT_NO is already define

Comment: i don't know if i have error on my cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue

Comment: The second time you are supposed to be defining @@STUDENT_ID you left it as @@STUDENT_NO instead.

Comment: You are adding parameter `@STUDENT_NO` twice to the command.remove line `AddWithValue("@STUDENT_NO"...` after line `AddWithValue("@QTR", ...`

Comment: if reusing the same parameters in a loop don't use AddWithValue it's a once-off.  Declare the parameters outside the loop (cmd.Paramters,Add(name, type) and then set the .Value inside the loop.

Comment: @Carter yes sir i change STUDENT_NO from my tbl_attendance to STUDENT_ID cause i'm getting an error saying that STUDENT_NO is already define yet even though that ive change STUDENT_NO to STUDENT_ID i'm still getting this error.

Comment: ... an item of note. When you add the additional query, "query += ...", there is no space. Use " INSERT..." instead of "INSERT..". Don't know if that is your only issue, but worth fixing.

Comment: @rob thank you so much sir anyway sir can you send me a link sir how to use that code?

Comment: @SteveJ copy that sir, thank's :)

Comment: @SteveJ - lack of space shouldn't be a problem - lack of terminating semicolon after the first insert will be though. One after the second is not necessary but good practice in case further inserts are added.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thank you sir :)

Comment: @Rob thank you so much sir

Comment: if it worked please mark as the answer

Comment: it not worked sir @Rob

Comment: sir @Rob have you experienced to import and load an excel file that has sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3 to datagridview and after that saved the data from sheet1 to tbl_1st, sheet2 to tbl_2nd and sheet3 to tbl_3rd to your database?? how did you handle that kind of scenarios sir?? using c#

Answer (score 0):

Quickie partial

```
...
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
cmd.Paramters.Add("@STUDENT_NO", MySqlDbType.Int); .. guessing this is an int - otherwise choose type
cmd.Paramters.Add("@NAME", MySqlDbType.String);
... // add rest here
con.Open();
...
for (.. ) {
    ...
    int studentno;
    int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["STUDENT NO"].Value.ToString(), out studentno);
    cmd.Paramters["@STUDENT_NO"].Value = studentno;
    cmd.Paramters["@NAME"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["NAME"].Value.ToString();
    ...
}
```